# Parse the DOM like Javascript using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a sample HTML in a variable html_doc like this :

```
html_doc =  """<table class="sample">
        <tbody>
        <tr class="title"><td colspan="2">Info</td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="light">Time</td>
        <td>01/01/1970, 00:00:00</td>
        </tr>
        <td class="highlight">URL</td>
        <td>https://test.com</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>"""
```

Using Javascript its pretty straightforward if I want to parse the DOM. But if I want to grab ONLY the URL `(https://test.com)` and `Time (01/01/1970, 00:00:00)` in 2 different variables from the `<td>` tag above, how can I do it if there is no class name associated with it.

My `test.py` file

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,'html.parser')
test = soup.find_all("td")
print(test)
```

Comment: Also the time from the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using regular expression to get the url

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,'html.parser')
test = soup.find_all("td")
for tag in test:
    urls = re.match('https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', tag.text)
    time = re.match('[0-9/:, ]+',tag.text)
    if urls!= None:
        print(urls.group(0))
    if time!= None:
        print(time.group(0))
```

Output

> 01/01/1970, 00:00:00
>   https://test.com

Comment: Also the time from the HTML

Answer (score 2):

You already got all `td` elements. You can iterate through all of them:

```
for td in soup.find_all('td'):
    if td.text.startswith('http'):
        print(td, td.text)
# <td>https://test.com</td> https://test.com
```

If you want, you can be a bit less explicit by searching for the `td` element with "highlight" class and find the next sibling, but this is more error prone in case the DOM will change:

```
for td in soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'highlight'}):
   print(td.find_next_sibling())
# <td>https://test.com</td>
```

Comment: Also the time from the html

Comment: @MaccenWright You can use the same approach to search for the time `td`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very specific solution. If you need a general approach, Hari Krishnan's solution with a few tweaks might be more suitable.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,'html.parser')
tds = []

for td in soup.find_all('td', {'class': ['highlight', 'light']}):
    tds.append(td.find_next_sibling().string)

time, link = tds
```

Answer (score 0):

With the reference of [@DeepSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1453822/deepspace)

```
import bs4, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc =  """<table class="sample">
        <tbody>
        <tr class="title"><td colspan="2">Info</td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="light">Time</td>
        <td>01/01/1970, 00:00:00</td>
        </tr>
        <td class="highlight">URL</td>
        <td>https://test.com</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>"""

datepattern = re.compile("\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}, \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,'html.parser')
for td in soup.find_all('td'):
    if td.text.startswith('http'):
        link = td.text
    elif datepattern.search(td.text):
        time = td.text
print(link, time)
```